# Error running java -jar command

Tags: java, jar, executable

I created a jar file using the following ANT script

```
<manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${bin.dir}/${jar.app.name}" maxparentlevels="0">
    <classpath refid="main.class.path" />
</manifestclasspath>
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/lib/isp"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/lib/jasper"/>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib/jasper">
            <fileset dir="${lib.jasper.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib/isp">
            <fileset dir="${lib.isp.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar jarfile="${bin.dir}/${jar.app.name}"
            index="true"
            basedir="${classes.dir}" excludes="lib/mytest.jar "
            >
            <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
            </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

The resulting jar file has the following MANIFEST.MF entry.

```
Main-Class: dm.jb.Main
Class-Path: lib/isp/OfficeLnFs_2.2.jar lib/isp/RXTXcomm.jar lib/isp/ba
rbecue-1.0.6d.jar lib/isp/commons-logging-1.1.jar lib/isp/forms-1.0.5
.jar lib/isp/gnujaxp.jar lib/isp/helpUI.jar lib/isp/inspInstaller.jar
 lib/isp/itext-2.0.1.jar lib/isp/itext-2.0.2.jar lib/isp/jcalendar-1.
3.2.jar lib/isp/jcl.jar lib/isp/jcommon-1.0.10.jar lib/isp/jcommon-1.
0.9.jar lib/isp/jdnc-0_7-all.jar lib/isp/jdnc-runner.jar lib/isp/jdom
.jar lib/isp/jfreechart-1.0.6.jar lib/isp/jlfgr-1_0.jar lib/isp/junit
.jar lib/isp/log4j-1.2.9.jar lib/isp/looks-1.3.2.jar lib/isp/msbase.j
ar lib/isp/mssqlserver.jar lib/isp/msutil.jar lib/isp/mysql-connector
```

When I try to run the command
`java -jar mytest.jar`, it fails and throws error saying dm.jb.Main not found. But I could run the class by specifying the classpath java -classpath  dm.jb.Main

Please help me
DM

Answer (score 1):

If you run your jar like this

```
java -jar <your jar name>
```

then java will ignore all classpath parameters you give and try to find it's resources with the given classpath inside the manifest. But these pathes point to your local file system and not inside the jar. So you have to start the jar in a directory where your libs can be found at lib/isp/...

Comment: I have a lib folder in the directory where I run the command and has all the required jar files exactly as mentioned the MANIFEST file. Still it does not work.